# Text to speech in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, text-to-speech

I am improving a small alarm/reminder application that I build years ago, and I would like to do an hourly beep, but instead of beeping it would be much nicer it would tell time.
Is there any simple way to do this in DELPHI D2007 or later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check Brian Long tutorial's
[**Speech Synthesis & Speech Recognition Using SAPI 5.1**](http://web.archive.org/web/20101003082259/http://www.blong.com/Conferences/DCon2002/Speech/SAPI51/SAPI51.htm)

I wrote a text to speech software using this tutorial.

It reads the clipboard content when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComObj;
```

[...]

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Voice: Variant;
begin
  Voice := CreateOLEObject('SAPI.SpVoice');
  Voice.speak('Hello World');
end;
```

Comment: we use this method in the field, no issues, works with xp/vista

Comment: I used the code above, it doesn't work in Vista. But with SpVoice component in Brian Long tutoriat it works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

I did a video awhile back on [making your applications talk](http://codegearguru.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=59&Itemid=27) in Delphi.  I personally haven't ever found a use for text to speech in one of my applications, but it's a fun thing to know how to do ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In my code I use MS Agent and TAgntSrvr component: 
http://delphi.icm.edu.pl/ftp/d30free/agntsrvr.htm

Also you can check this [link](http://www.delphiforfun.org/Programs/texttospeech.htm) or just Google around: "text speech delphi"

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[eSpeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/)** with Delphi to support more languages and Mac (and hopefully Linux in the future). Delphi example is **[here](http://www.rolfware.de/delphi/espeak_example.html)**.